# Java - Can I call any number of methods in my remote object?

Tags: java, rmi

In all the examples I have seen, the Interface that extends the Remote class has only one Method.

Can I have as many Methods I want in this Interface and implement it in the Server program, so that my client program call call them? For example: One method will be to get an object and another to store an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about RMI, then yes you can put what you want in there, as many methods as you choose.